# insert time in one row from differnt files in R

Tags: r

I have 23 seperate files (with 70 headers)for each hours (0 to 23) for the period 2009-2017. I need to merge the time/Date in one rows.

for example:

hour_0.txt

```
    Date                       A1    A2  .  .  .  . A75
2009-01-01 00:30:00            10   11              value
2009-01-02 00:30:00            12   13              value
2009-01-03 00:30:00            14   15              value
.
.
.
2017-01-29 00:30:00            16   17   .  .  .  . value
2017-01-30 00:30:00            18   19              value
```

hour_1.txt

```
    Date                       A1    A2  .  .  .  . A75
2009-01-01 01:30:00            20   21              value
2009-01-02 01:30:00            22   23              value
2009-01-03 01:30:00            24   25              value
.
.
.
2017-01-29 01:30:00            26   27.  .  .  .  . value
2017-01-30 01:30:00            28   29              value
```

I want to create the Final file including all hour files like

```
    Date                       A1    A2  .  .  .  . value
2009-01-01 00:30:00            10   11              value
2009-01-01 01:30:00            20   21              value
2009-01-01 02:30:00            value value          value
2009-01-01 03:30:00            value value          value
.
.
2009-01-02 00:30:00            12     13           value
2009-01-02 01:30:00            22     23           value
2009-01-02 02:30:00            value value         value
```

I tried `rbind(hour_0,hour_1)` and `merge(hour_0,hour_1, by='Date')` but could not solve it. 
So any idea?
I am getting the results like (for e.g. for hour1.txt and hour2.txt)

```
    Date                       A1    A2  .  .  .  . A75
2009-01-01 00:30:00            value value          value
2009-01-01 00:30:00            value value          value
2009-01-01 00:30:00            value value          value
2009-01-01 00:30:00            value value          value
.
.
2017-12-30 00:30:00
.
.
2009-01-02 01:30:00
2009-01-02 01:30:00
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question from the information that you've given. Can you add more information, including a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what happens when you try `rbind()` and `merge()`?

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope this time it will give better information.

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

```
df_new <- rbind(data.frame(hour_0, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
 data.frame(hour_1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```